# Modificar Correlativo

Tags: javascript, asp

Estoy armando una tabla con js en asp donde una columna se llama correlativo y estoy usando un for para que automaticamente detecte el correlativo, hasta ahi todo bien porque me funciona, pero por ejemplo si tengo 15 filas, (correlativo del 1 al 15), pero si en el correlativo 4, cambio el número a 10, necesito que automaticamente el resultado sea 11, 12, y asi sucesivamente. (Ver imagen)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<script>
function crear(){
        var col = 4
        var filas = 15
        var tabla="<div id=\"central\"><table class=\"table table-bordered table-lg table-v2 table-striped\" cellpadding=\"3\" cellspacing=\"3\" border=\"1\">";
        tabla+="<td>"+("CABECERA")+ "</td>";
        tabla+="<td>"+("CORRELATIVO")+ "</td>";
        tabla+="<td>"+("PRODUCTO")+ "</td>";
        tabla+="<td>"+("FECHA")+ "</td>";
        tabla+="</tr>";

    for(i=0;i<filas;i++){
        tabla+="<tr>";
        tabla+="<td>"+"DATO "+(i+1)+"</td>"
        tabla+="<td>"+"<input id=\"correlativo"+(i+1)+"\" name=\"correlativo"+(i+1)+"\" value=\""+(i+1)+"\" type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\">"+ "</td>";
        tabla+="<td>"+"<input name=\"producto"+(i+1)+"\" value=\"<%=(producto)%>\" type=\"text\" size=\"1\" class=\"form-control\">"+ "</td>";
        tabla+="<td>"+"<input id=\"fecha"+(i+1)+"\" name=\"fecha"+(i+1)+"\" oninput=\"ValidarFechaHTML5(this)\" onBlur=\"ValidarFecha(this)\" placeholder=\"dd/mm/yyyy\" type=\"text\" class=\"fecha form-control\">"+ "</td>";
        tabla+="</tr>";
    }
        tabla+="</div></table>";
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=tabla;
}
```

Necesito que quede como en la imagen
No sé como realizar este correlativo modificable, por favor si me pueden ayudar, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Puedes agregar un *listener* del *change* a cada input, de manera que cuando se modifique algún valor, cambie los valores siguientes. Para eso sería mas conveniente utilizar clases, aquí un ejémplo:

```
const correlativos = [...document.getElementsByClassName("correlativos")];

correlativos.forEach((c, i) => {
  c.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
    let nextVal = +e.target.value + 1;
    for (let k = (i + 1); k < correlativos.length; k++) {
      correlativos[k].value = nextVal++;
    }

  })

});
```

Puedes ver un ejémplo completo aquí https://jsfiddle.net/dm251f3o/

Si quisieras optimizar el código, podrías agregar los *listeners* al momento de crear los inputs, de manera ahorrar iteraciones.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, implementaré el código para probarlo, mi consulta es la siguiente, cuando declaras la const correlativos = [...document.getElementsByClassName("correlativos")];, que va en los puntos ...., lo consulto, porque mucho no entiendo de js, y todo lo que he aplicado lo he ido aprendiendo poco a poco.

Comment: @Karli En los puntos no va nada, es la forma de convertir eso en un array, y se llama Asignación por destructuring https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: Emeeus, muchas gracias por la aclaración, he implementado el código a mi código, pero me arroja este error Uncaught TypeError: c.addEventListener is not a function, es decir que debo crear una funcion para esto, o no es asi?

Comment: eso te lo está arrojando porque lo que estás iterando no son elements

Comment: Disculpa mi ignorancia, pero que significa eso, porque cuando yo cargo mi código viene mi correlativo asignado, pero me arroja dicho error, si no trae elemento debería venir vacío y no es así.  Obvio que estoy haciendo mal y no me logro dar cuenta de eso, como en cada caso que avanzo aprendo cosas nuevas!

Comment: Si tienes algo como `correlativos.forEach`, `correlativos` tiene que si o si ser un array. Si a cada item de la iteración (que en el ejemplo llamamos `c`) le hacemos `.addEventListener`, `c` tiene que si o si ser un elemento del DOM.  Si te dice que addEventListener no es una función, quiere decir que aparentemente tienes un array pero no de elementos del DOM, por lo que tienes que revisar la creación del array, osea el equivalente a `const correlativos = [...document.getElementsByClassName("correlativos")];` en el ejemplo de la respuesta